# Connect outer the Gates (AND ,OR)

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

I have the equation `L=ABD+(A+B)(D+C)`.
I have this [image]

I must connect those based on the equation.
What I did was to take the equation

```
L=ABD+(A+B)(D+C)
```

and make it simplier
so I have `L=ABD+AD+AC+BD+BC`
At my view I can't simplifie it more.

I must connect  outter those Gates AND,OR based on my equation.

In the picture,on the left side I have the gate AND ,on the right of the picture I have the gate OR.

Now, about **gate AND**: I know I have input 1 and 2, the 3 is output. Also,4,5 are also inputs and 6 is output. 7 is the ground. 14 is output for Vcc.13,12 are used as inputs and 11 as output.
10 and 9 inputs and 8 output.

Similar we have and the OR gate.

I think that I can connect the Gate AND with OR by the outputs. I mean the gate AND output 3 can be connected with the inputs of gate OR.

From the equation, how can I do that based on the equation? because I can't understand.

Comment: I can't understand what is "by the input", "by the output" and similar. Draw a logical schematic of the circuit you want to build, then simply use the gates in the chips to build it. Your "simplified" equation requires much more gates than the original one by the way.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  by the input,I mean if you look the 74HCT08. The numbers represents inputs,outputs,GNC and Vcc.If you look inside there is already a gate there.Which gate is AND.

Comment: draw this kind of diagram first, worry about pin numbers after ... https://www.101computing.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/diagram-4.png

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: It can be simplified more!  Absorption Law X + X Y = X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Suppose you want to compute ABD+AD. Follow these steps:

1. Using one AND gate, compute A AND B.
2. Using another AND gate compute A AND D.
3. Using another AND gate compute D and the result of step 1.
4. Using an OR gate compute the OR of the results of steps 2 and 3.

The desired output will be the output of the OR gate.

Comment: you mean that from the AND gates after I find the outputs I will send those to Inputs of OR gates?

Comment: Yes, that's right!